# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') querySelector

Tags: javascript, typeerror, queryselector

i'm doing projects from this vídeo (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PHXvlpOkf4&t=421s)
and i stuck at 4 project (the reviews project)
I would like to know if you could help me

[i recive  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null" and search for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qZ5G.jpg)

[referring to the following line of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKYUP.jpg)

[I have this DOM object that is selecting buttons from my HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8tMa.png)

[html buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfNV2.jpg)

[and this function being called inside the addEventListener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmjt6.jpg)

in practice, the script should move forward or backward profile of people, but when loading the page I always come across this error, as if my querySelector was not able to select the passed class
when I give a console log it shows null value for all queryselector

I've tried everything that knowledge allowed me, I hope you can help me and thank you in advance

Comment: Hello! Would you mind putting your code here instead of screenshots of it? You can use the JavaScript/HTML/CSS button to insert your code.

Comment: maybe this will be better, I'm still learning to use stakoverlow, this is literally my first post

https://codepen.io/l4rs89/pen/VwVKXGr

Comment: You can post here with a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). This is similar to CodePen and jsfiddle, but it doesn't require an external link.

Comment: The CodePen is getting a different error: `nextBtn is not defined`. You need something like `const nextBtn = document.querySelector("#next-btn");`

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback, I solved the error by putting the shortcut to the JS file inside the body instead of in the head and the error stopped happening and the logic worked normally